# Mysql: How to see the compile time configs of a mysql binary

Tags: mysql, configuration, compilation

I installed mysql using apt-get on my local machine recently.
It proceeded with the default my.cnf.
I would like to see what are the compile time configurations of this binary.

Can some one help me how can i do this?

Comment: Do you want to use c API to connect to MySQL? In that case you need to install libmysqlclient package

Comment: No I am not using any programming language.

Comment: Uday, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install mysql-server source.

```
apt-get source mysql-server # root access not needed
```

This will create some archive files in the current directory. In my debian lenny it creates the following directories. In your Ubuntu it'll be almost same.

```
 mysql-dfsg-5.0-5.0.51a
 mysql-dfsg-5.0_5.0.51a-24+lenny5.diff.gz
 mysql-dfsg-5.0_5.0.51a-24+lenny5.dsc
 mysql-dfsg-5.0_5.0.51a.orig.tar.gz
```

Now inspect the `debian/rules` file in extracted source. I did it by this,

```
  less mysql-dfsg-5.0-5.0.51a/debian/rules
```

You can use other editor (`nano`, `vi`, `gedit` all are okay). Arround line `68` you'll see the configuration option

To know more about how to recompile a debian source package, read

- [Howto recompile debian packages](http://www.ducea.com/2008/03/06/howto-recompile-debian-packages/)
- [Compiling Debian or Ubuntu Source Packages](http://blog.cachemiss.com/articles/Compiling%20Debian%20or%20Ubuntu%20Source%20Packages.pod)

Comment: Thanks mokadd.... If i install using apt-get once... can i be able to re compile again. Suppose if the binary don't have ssl support, then shall i be able to recompile again....

Comment: source packages are for compilation. You can recompile and create another deb from it.

Comment: U mean... In case if no support in the binary and I want ssl support, that binary will be of no use to me. is it...?

Comment: If you want ssl support you need openssl library install. Then configure the mysql with open ssl include path. The switch will be something like `--with-ssl`.

Comment: sorry to ask you again... I didnt understand.  If I want ssl support, I need to get the new binary which will support ssl and need to install open ssl and need to use --with-ssl while compiling. Or can I do this with the existing binary itself....?

Comment: @Uday check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/source-configuration-options.html "MySQL Source-Configuration Options").  Also I suggest you read [How to install Mysql from source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/source-installation.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10593/discussion-between-uday-and-shiplu-mokadd-im)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
shell> mysql_config
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep CONFIG $(which mysqlbug)
```

[Source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3595/determine-configure-options-used-for-mysql-binary-builds)